# Privacy manifest requirement for iOS SDKs

Tags: ios, manifest, privacy

**Context:** the new iOS enforcement of Privacy manifests is slated for In [Spring 2024](https://developer.apple.com/news/?id=r1henawx) Apple will require any app with a dependency on one of their [determined SDKs](https://developer.apple.com/support/third-party-SDK-requirements/) to provide a privacy manifest file showing how they utilize relevant data types and APIs.

**Question:** As a developer with a dependency on one of these SDKs, do I need to update my existing app with a privacy manifest if it already includes one of these SDKs, or will I only be subject to add a privacy manifest for my existing app if I **newly added** one of these listed SDKs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As how i understand your question and [apple's](https://developer.apple.com/news/?id=r1henawx) privacy update it is mandatory to add a privacy manifest to your app, existing or new ones, when they get updated. Quote:

> When you upload a new app or app update to App Store Connect that uses an API (including from third-party SDKs) that requires a reason, you’ll receive a notice if you haven’t provided an approved reason in your app’s privacy manifest

Further information: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/privacy_manifest_files/describing_use_of_required_reason_api